# LinQ Remove products based on Status

Tags: c#, linq, xamarin.forms

So I have a issue with a API showing drafted products.

So my solution is to iterate over the list before my view is set and remove any drafted products.

However i'm not familiar with LinQ so im not exactly sure how to go about this, Or what to Phrase id use to look into this more

Here are my attempts

Attempt 1: only removes 1 Product(If I say Any|All its just says cannot convert bool to product)

```
  var listitem = (from itm in products where itm.status == "draft" select itm).FirstOrDefault();
                products.Remove(listitem);
  //Also tried something like

.Where(a => a.status == "draft")
```

Attempt 2: Finds the item, But then removes everything

```
       foreach (var item in products)
                {
                    if (item.status == "draft")
                    {
                        products.Remove(item);
                    }
                }
```

```
      productsListView.FlowItemsSource = products;
```

Whats the correct way of doing this?

Comment: product.Select((item)=>(item.status!="draft"))

Comment: I mean yes, But how do I remove the product? If i say var y = product.Select((item)=>(item.status!="draft")); products.Remove(y); Same situation cannot convert bool to Product

Comment: This will get all the products where the status is not equal to draft . You need not remove the product .

Comment: The Logic was helpful, But returning a Collection of Boolean wont assist me in this use case thank you tho.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have a issue with a API showing drafted products. So my solution is to ... remove any drafted products.

Not sure what you want. Do you want to show only the drafted products? Or do you want to show all non-drafted products? Maybe you want to remove the drafted products from your original list?

**Show only the drafted products**

```
var draftedProducts = products.Where(product => product.Status == "draft);
```

In words: from the original sequence of products, keep the products that have a value for property Status equal to "draft"

It is usually easier to understand if you follow the conventions: sequences (collections, lists, arrays) are plural nouns. Elements of the sequence are singular nouns. The part before `=>` represents one element of the sequence, the part after `=>` represents the expression that works on the element of the sequence

**Show only non-drafted products**

If you understand the previous attempt, this one won't be difficult to understand:

```
 var nonDraftedProducts = products.Where(product => product.Status != "draft);
```

**Remove the drafted products from your original collection**

> It is important to understand: LINQ will never change your input sequences. LINQ will not add or remove items to the input sequences, nor will it change any of the properties.

If you want to remove items from your input sequences, you'll have to iterate over the LINQ result and remove the items.

```
var draftedProducts = products.Where(product => product.Status == "draft).ToList();
foreach (var draftedProduct in draftedProducts)
{
    products.Remove(draftedProduct);
}
```

Or to remove them from a database:

```
using (var dbContext = new ProductsDbContext)
{
    var draftedProducts = dbContext.Products
        .Where(product => product.Status == "draft)
        .ToList();
    dbContext.Products.RemoveRange(draftedProducts);
}
```

Or if you use SQL to access the Products:

```
var allProducts = myDatabase.GetAllProducts();
var draftedProducts = dbContext.Products
        .Where(product => product.Status == "draft)
        .ToList();
foreach (var draftedProduct in draftedProducts)
{
    myDatabase.RemoveProduct(draftedProduct);
}
```

Comment: Wow! Great answer Harald Thank you for taking the time to write this. I did want to remove drafted products but Gathering from everyones logic its best to just display the Non drafted products. Although Ricchi's answer did solve my problem and so does this, This is extremely detailed and will surely assist the next person,

Answer (score 2):

How about

> productsListView.FlowItemsSource = products.Where(p => p.status != "draft");

Does this work?